# ¿Cómo crear reportes con columnas dinámicas usando Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema ya que an no encuentro información como lo que necesito hacer.

Tengo un usuario que entra a la aplicación web, consulta datos y los datos se muestran en un `grid`.

El `grid` puede contener 7 columnas, 8 columnas, 5 columnas etcétera, las columnas varían dependiendo el usuario que entra en la aplicación.

Lo que he visto en algunos artículos es que ponen las columnas para seleccionarlas y dependiendo del numero de columnas seleccionadas estas se muestran en el reporte. Pero para mi no me sirve que se seleccionen las columnas ya que el usuario ya trae las columnas establecidas y no son fijas ya que en una consulta el grid puede traer 5 columnas pero en otra consulta le agregaron información y puede traer 7 columnas el `grid`.

Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo crear este reporte con las columnas que se muestran el `grid`?

En el diseño de mi reporte yo coloque todas las columnas pero cuando un usuario descarga el reporte y solo 5 columnas traen información de un total de 8 columnas, las 3 columnas restantes se quedan vacías y por tanto al no tener datos los usuarios se confunden.

Espero me puedan ayudar o decirme si es posible hacerlo y como hacerlo de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Me parece que lo que quieres hacer, puedes lograrlo usando _"Reportes Crosstab"_ investiga un poco sobre este tema.

Comment: Hola @J.Rodríguez al parecer no me funciona este tipo de reporte mas bien necesito crearlo por medio de código ya que necesito ocultar las columnas que no tengan información, por otra parte si agregan otra columna a mi procedimiento almacenado debería de reflejarlo en el reporte. El ocultamiento de columnas ya lo tengo realizado solo me falta cargar el datatable a mi reporte en blanco. ¿Sabes como puedo cargar el datatable a un reporte en blanco?. Gracias.

Comment: Yo ha haría el reporte para el máximo de columnas y luego las ocultaría o bien desde el informe pasando un parámetro o mediante programacion puedes acceder a los campos y ocultarlo y/o cambiar el ancho y la posición, pero claro, siempre diseñando para el máximo número de columnas. Dinámicamente no puedes añadir o quitar columnas, solo mostrar u ocultar